# SlideIn/Out content by data-attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use a simple slideIn/Out script by clicking on a link. My problem, if I click on a link to slideIN the content, all other content-boxes also slide in their content, because there is no attribute with which they can seperate the content boxes. So I think the "data-attribute" will be a good way?

The plan, the script should compare the "data-attribute" from the link with the "data-attribute" from the content:

```
<div class="button" data-filter="1">Show</div>
<div class="text" data-filter="1">Bla1 bla1 bla1</div>

<div class="button" data-filter="2">Show</div>
<div class="text" data-filter="2">Bla2 bla2 bla2</div>
```

Is there a simple way?
That is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dw6936L3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get the clicked attribute value with [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). Then use it in the proceeding selector to find the `.text` element with that attribute value

```
var attrVal = $(this).attr('data-filter');
$box = $('.text[data-filter="'+attrVal+'"]');
```

Alternatively, you can use [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) like

```
$box = $(this).prev();
```

This works because this will get you the immediate preceding element(which happens to be `.text`).

```js
$(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(){
        var attrVal = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $box = $(this).prev();
        minimumHeight = 100;
        
        // get current height
        currentHeight = $box.innerHeight();

        // get height with auto applied
        autoHeight = $box.css('height', 'auto').innerHeight();
        
        // reset height and revert to original if current and auto are equal
        $box.css('height', currentHeight).animate({
            height: (currentHeight == autoHeight ? minimumHeight : autoHeight)
        })
    });
})
```

```css
.text{
  height:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text" data-filter="1">bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
</div>
<div class="button" data-filter="1">Show</div><br /><br />

<div> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div><br /><br />

<div class="text" data-filter="2">bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
</div>
<div class="button" data-filter="2">Show</div><br /><br />

<div class="text" data-filter="3">bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
    <br />
    bla bla bla bla
</div>
<div class="button" data-filter="3">Show</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `data-*` attributes, but **[`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)** can also be used.

```
$box = $(this).prev(".text");
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dw6936L3/1/)**

or with `data-filter` use attribute based selector with `.data()`,

```
$box = $(".text[data-filter="+$(this).data('filter')+"]");
```

Comment: Also big thx!! Your prev. way works too, but AmmarCSE was a bit faster and I focused the "data-filter" way ... but thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.prev()` to refer to immediate previous sibling from the current element.

I would also like to suggest you to enclose the related dom elements within a container `div` as it makes the `DOM` easy to understand & looks well organised.

**JS code:**

```
$(function () {
 $(".button").click(function () {
    $box = $(this).prev('.text'); //get previous sibling
    minimumHeight = 100;

    // get current height
    currentHeight = $box.innerHeight();

    // get height with auto applied
    autoHeight = $box.css('height', 'auto').innerHeight();

    // reset height and revert to original if current and auto are equal
    $box.css('height', currentHeight).animate({
        height: (currentHeight == autoHeight ? minimumHeight : autoHeight)
    });
  });
});
```

**Live demo @ JSFiddle :**

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/dw6936L3/8/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap the necessary `.text` divs and buttons into separate divs and then use `siblings` to target the correct text div.

http://jsfiddle.net/karanmhatre/dw6936L3/9/

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div class="text" data-filter="1">bla bla bla bla
        <br />
        bla bla bla bla
        <br />
        bla bla bla bla
        <br />
        bla bla bla bla
        <br />
        bla bla bla bla
        <br />
        bla bla bla bla
        <br />
        bla bla bla bla
        <br />
        bla bla bla bla
        <br />
        bla bla bla bla
    </div>
    <div class="button" data-filter="1">Show</div><br /><br />
</div>

<div> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div><br /><br />

<div>
    <div class="text" data-filter="2">bla bla bla bla
        <br />
        bla bla bla bla
        <br />
        bla bla bla bla
        <br />
        bla bla bla bla
        <br />
        bla bla bla bla
        <br />
        bla bla bla bla
        <br />
        bla bla bla bla
        <br />
        bla bla bla bla
        <br />
        bla bla bla bla
    </div>
    <div class="button" data-filter="2">Show</div><br /><br />
</div>

<div>
    <div class="text" data-filter="3">bla bla bla bla
        <br />
        bla bla bla bla
        <br />
        bla bla bla bla
        <br />
        bla bla bla bla
        <br />
        bla bla bla bla
        <br />
        bla bla bla bla
        <br />
        bla bla bla bla
        <br />
        bla bla bla bla
        <br />
        bla bla bla bla
    </div>
    <div class="button" data-filter="3">Show</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(){
        $box = $(this).siblings(".text");
        minimumHeight = 100;

        // get current height
        currentHeight = $box.innerHeight();

        // get height with auto applied
        autoHeight = $box.css('height', 'auto').innerHeight();

        // reset height and revert to original if current and auto are equal
        $box.css('height', currentHeight).animate({
            height: (currentHeight == autoHeight ? minimumHeight : autoHeight)
        });
    });
})
```

Feel like this is a far cleaner solution as opposed to trying to detect them using data filters.